# The system can not be solved

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to solve this equation:

```
   f[a_][r_]=((a*r/12)*(1+(r/12))^n)/(((1+(r/12))^n) - 1)
```

When I type `Solve[f[a][r]==p, a]` 
everything works fine. But when I type
When I type `Solve[f[a][r]==p, r]` Mathematica gives me: `This system cannot be solved with the methods available to solve`

What am I missing here? What should I use in order to compute this function according to r?

Comment: For arbitrary `n`, your equation is transcendental in `r`, so a closed-form is unlikely.

Comment: Take something as simple as `r + r^n == 1` and think about how you would solve it manually for $r \in \mathbb{C}$ for arbitrary (complex) $n$.  Mathematica is simply not able to compute a general symbolic solution under such general conditions.  Even if we restrict $n$ to integers, the number of solutions will depend on $n$.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. This problem of equations with symbolic variables or parameters in both the base and exponent seems to arise from time to time.  Should this be an [tag:faq]? If it is to be put on hold, perhaps there is a duplicate? (Of course, it's possible that a particular equation happens to be solvable.)

Comment: @Michael, I believe it does crop up a lot, but offhand I cannot recall if we have *good* prior threads that can be tagged [tag:faq].

Comment: @Michael Since this issue comes up repeatedly and we apparently lack a canonical original I am voting to leave this open.  If you find an original flag this and I shall fix it.